# Best way to convert configurable products to simple products

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, convert

A client has a lot of configurable products which contain just one simple product. The thinking behind this is that it will be easier to add products when the manufacturer ads new variants of the products.

The problem we have now is that every time a visitor selects the options, he finds just one option. for example: A T-shirts has just one color and one size selectable via the dropdown selectors.

I'm looking for a solution to convert all configurable products which have just one associated product assigned to it to a regular simple product.

can this be done by doing an export and finding all configurable products with just one simple product and by copy and paste the image url etc..

Hopesomeone has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Technically configurable products ARE simple products.

In Magento a configurable product is comprised of simple products which have permutations of values that make the parent unique. These attribute values, called **super configurable attributes**, are the values that make each SKU unique.

### Example

Let's take an example of a t-shirt. Our t-shirt can have two super configurable attributes, **size and color**. For simplicity let's say we only offer two variants of each of those attributes:

- Red Small T-shirt
- Green Small T-shirt
- Red Large T-shirt
- Green Large T-shirt

Easy enough.

For a configurable product to be... well... *configured*; you would have to have created each of those simple SKUs. That means that you likely have those simple SKUs already.

So, **no conversion is needed.** Simply make sure that each of those simples are now **Visible** and **In Stock** and **not Disabled**. Then assign them to a category and you should be in business!

Comment: Hi, that's an option if you have a few products but we have more than thousand products. All associated (simple)products don't have images. So we must do an export to copy over the images columns.